# Rescaling DEM for Blender

Tags: arcmap, dem, hillshade, map-algebra, blendergis

I'm working on getting some DEMs ready to bring into Blender to render hillshade. I've done this successfully before with low elevations, but on my current project mountaintops seem to get cut off.

When I mosaic the data or rescale it using the map algebra tool, the highest elevations turn white (in a greyscale scheme), and lose all detail. Does anyone know that causes this or have a possible solution?

EDIT: Changing the stretch type from the default (Standard Deviations) to Minimum-Maximum and changing those values to the ones used in my rescale math did the trick!

Comment: This is because ArcGIS is making assumptions about how you want to display these data and not because of data loss.  Go into the layer properties/Symbology.  Set the Stretch type to none and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Post pictures of your data/model in Blender. Make sure it's not the camera clip preventing you from seeing far distances, by default, I think it's limited to 1.000 units.

What add-on are you using? BlenderGIS? If so, try reaching the developer, I've done it once, he is very accessible.

Answer (score 2):

As @Marcos Salto said, I would bet on the view distance. If you could share an screenshot this could be more easy to figure it out.

Here is where you have to set the view:
[image]